Prime symbol appears in superscript while loading unicode-math
When I use the unicode-math package, the \prime symbol appears in the superscript position. Could you please advise how to solve this issue?
Compiler: lualatex-dev.exe (2024)
My MWE is below.
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table,pdfversion = 2.0}}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

The first section of this chapter consists of a brief and informal overview of the topics addressed in the book, in which only terms and notions familiar Body matter First column Footnote content with two lines. 

$$G = \prime ' \frac{E}{2 (\sigma +1)}$$
\end{document}



Isn't this expected?

Off-topic: do not use $$ ... $$ in LaTeX

unicode-math maps \prime to U+2032 in operatorfont which here is Latin Modern Math.  The glyph is already raised.

Regarding the duplicate: isn't this the opposite problem? In the other question the asker seems to want regular superscript (because other variants are described as 'horrible'), whereas here the OP seems to want a big prime on the baseline. The answers to the other question only address getting a (single) superscript prime as output, and they don't explain how to get the low prime when using unicode-math.
